# Pandas iterations to Pyspark Function

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Given a dataset I tried to create a logic where within two column I need to enforce continuity in terms of last destination (in to column) being the exact next starting point (in from column) per id. For instance this table

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | from  | to    |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | A     | B     |
|  1 | C     | A     |
|  2 | D     | D     |
|  2 | F     | G     |
|  2 | F     | F     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

should ideally look like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | from  | to    |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | A     | B     |
|  1 | B     | C     |
|  1 | C     | A     |
|  2 | D     | D     |
|  2 | D     | F     |
|  2 | F     | G     |
|  2 | G     | F     |
|  2 | F     | F     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Using Pandas I did this by looping row wise and checking if previous_row['to'] == current_row['from'], also a check for id that can be probably avoided using a groupby, as you may see below

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (i < (len(df)-1)):
        if (new.ix[i,"to"] != new.ix[i+1,"from"]) & (new.ix[i,"id"] == new.ix[i+1,"id"]): 
            new_index = i + 0.5
            line = pd.DataFrame({"id":new.ix[i,"id"],
                             "from":new.ix[i,"to"],"to":new.ix[i+1,"from"],}, index = [new_index])
            appendings = pd.concat([appendings,line])
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Is it possible to as is  "translate" this to pyspark rdds?

I am aware that looping is far from optimal in Pyspark to replicate a looping and if-else logic.

I considered grouping by and zipping from and to columns and working on a single column. Main problem with this lies in the fact that I could produce a flag on lines that are "faulty" but there is no way to insert new lines without using index-wise operations.

Comment: in spark, the order of rows are non-deterministic after shuffling(i.e. groupby, window), you need to specify at least one column to sort so the order of rows can be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a `pyspark` answer but a partial answer to show you how to achieve the task without loop in **`pandas`**.

You can try:

```
def f(sub_df):
    return sub_df.assign(to_=np.roll(sub_df.To, 1)) \
                .apply(lambda x: [[x.From, x.To]] if x.to_ == x.From else [[x.to_, x.From], [x.From, x.To]], axis=1) \
                .explode() \
                .apply(pd.Series)


out = df.groupby('id').apply(f) \
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
        .rename(columns={0: "from", 1: "to"})
```

---

**Workflow:**

- Group the dataframe by `id` using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- For each group:

  - Create a new column (here names `to_`) to have the previous row. [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) performs a **circular shift** in order to keep the last value.
  - According if the *current from* == *previous to*: return current line or add a new line to make the transition.
  - Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to explode the `list` of `list` into one list per row.
  - Convert the column into two columns using [`apply(pd.Series)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)
- Then, for the output dataframe, remove the *level 1* index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- And rename the columns using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

---

**Full code**

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,2,2,2], "From": ["A", "C", "D", "F", "F"], "To": ["B", "D", "D", "G", "F"]})
# print(df)


def f(sub_df):
    return sub_df.assign(to_=np.roll(sub_df.To, 1)) \
                .apply(lambda x: [[x.From, x.To]] if x.to_ == x.From else [[x.to_, x.From], [x.From, x.To]], axis=1) \
                .explode() \
                .apply(pd.Series)


out = df.groupby('id').apply(f) \
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
        .rename(columns={0: "from", 1: "to"})
print(out)
#    from to
# id
# 1     D  A
# 1     A  B
# 1     B  C
# 1     C  D
# 2     F  D
# 2     D  D
# 2     D  F
# 2     F  G
# 2     G  F
# 2     F  F
```

The next step is to translate it into `PySpark`. Try it and feel free to open a new question with yours attempts.